# How do I make Visual Studio copy JS files from compiled TypeScript with Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, compilation, msbuild, visual-studio-2022

I have a non-web project (WPF) in **Visual Studio 2022** and the UI uses HTML/CSS/Javascript. I want to compile TypeScript on built as well and copy the compiled JS files into built folder.

This is my `tsconfig.json` file so it compile files in `Scripts` folder into `WebApp\js` folder (Scripts folder won't be copied and is not neccessary)

```json
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "WebApp/js/",
        "rootDir": "Scripts/"
        // Other options
    },
    "exclude": [
        "WebApp/"
    ]
}
```

This is my `csproj` file to include and copy all files in `WebApp` folder (note that `tsconfig.json` is Content so `Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild` follows the instruction in that file):

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="WebApp\**">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="tsconfig.json" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" Version="4.6.4">
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- Other items -->
```

The problem is, apparently the copy is executed **before** the TypeScript build so my files are never copied unless I build the project twice.

I tried adding a [`<Copy>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/copy-task?view=vs-2022) task as well with `AfterTargets` set to `Build` but even so the copied files are before TypeScript compilation.

How do I make TypeScript compilation task to run before the copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the target I create should have `AfterTargets` with `CompileTypeScriptWithTSConfig` value. I got the value thanks to running `dotnet build -verbosity:normal` to get all the name of actual targets.

```xml
    <Target Name="CopyTypeScriptCompiledFiles" AfterTargets="CompileTypeScriptWithTSConfig">
        <ItemGroup>
            <CompiledTypeScriptJs Include="WebApp\js\**" />
        </ItemGroup>
        
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(CompiledTypeScriptJs)"
              DestinationFiles="$(OutputPath)WebApp\js\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </Target>
```

I also used a wrong symbol (`$` instead of `@`) in the Copy's `SourceFiles` attribute before so no file got copied.